# OnSelectedIndexChanged of asp.net DropDownList which is outside datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, checkbox, datalist

I have a DataList that contains CheckBoxList,  and I filter the datalist on `selectedindexchanged` outside datalist. The problem is when I select value from dropdownlist I can't get the checked values from database
and `checkboxlist` items count is 0

this is the code

```
  protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string GroupValue;
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString().IsEmpty()) { GroupValue = null; } else { GroupValue = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString(); }

        if (pageMode == PageMode.Update)
        {
            int rowID = int.Parse(GrdUsers.GetRowValues(GrdUsers.FocusedRowIndex, "ID").ToString());
            //ConnectionLayer cn = new ConnectionLayer();
            //DataTable dt = cn.ExecutQuery("PagesSys", new object[] { 0, DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() });
            //dlstPages.DataSource = dt;
            //dlstPages.DataBind();

            BindOption(rowID);

        }
  private void BindOption(int UserID)
{
    try
    {
        if (pageMode == PageMode.Update)
        {
            if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value != "-1")
            {

                dlstPages.DataSource = ViewState["FunctionOption"];
                dlstPages.DataBind();

                if (dlstPages.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dlstPages.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new Users().UserPrivilege(UserID, int.Parse(dlstPages.DataKeys[i].ToString()));

                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns["OptionId"] };
                            CheckBoxList chklist = (CheckBoxList)dlstPages.Items[i].FindControl("chkOption");

                            for (int j = 0; j < chklist.Items.Count; j++)
                            {
                                if (dt.Rows.Find(chklist.Items[j].Value) != null)
                                {
                                    chklist.Items[j].Selected = true;
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the arguments to the function to get the dropdown list object, then you can find the selected value. Something like:

```
DropDownList ddl= (DropDownList)sender;
var value = ddl.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Comment: for (int j = 0; j < chklist.Items.Count; j++)
                            {}  the itams.count is 0

Comment: I was just trying to point you in the right direction, I don't really understand what you've posted. It looks a lot from your post like BindOption is defined within DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged which I don't think can be correct, also and the 'try' with an empty 'catch' will just hide problems. I was just trying to show you how to get the selected value from the dropdownlist.